# TypeError: Can't convert Array into Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting the following error:

```
can't convert Array into Hash
```

Here's the application trace:

```
app/models/channel.rb:21:in `search'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:107:in `browse'
```

The following code is from channel.rb (referenced in the app trace), where line 21 is "tire.search...":

```
def self.search(params)
  tire.search(['posts_index', 'channels_index'],{load: true}) do
    query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present? 
    sort { by :created_at, "desc" } if params[:query].blank?
  end
end
```

I've also included the browse action of posts_controller.rb, also referenced in the trace above:

```
def browse
    @user = current_user
    @channels = Channel.search(params)
    @posts = Post.search(params)
end
```

My goal is to search multiple indexes using Tire/ElasticSearch. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the top of your stacktrace?

Comment: You bet, I've added it above – along with some more detail. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: In my application, indexes are same as table name and i have used(Tire is capital as its a class): Tire.search(['posts', 'channels'],{load: true})

Comment: @cmw: have u tried the code mentioned in upper comment ?

Comment: What is `tire`?  Searching is typically done with `Tire.search` (i.e. a class method).

Answer (score 0):

Hey try to add the "**load: true**" with out giving the *curly braces*. It worked for me...

```
def self.search(params)
  tire.search(['posts_index', 'channels_index'],load: true) do
    query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present? 
    sort { by :created_at, "desc" } if params[:query].blank?
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion – this didn't seem to work for me, however. The same error persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up phrasing this question a bit differently – and was able to resolve it. See: [Search multiple models with Tire and ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950470/search-multiple-models-with-tire-and-elasticsearch)