# Tire/Mongoid Single Table Inheritance - Searching over mutliple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, elasticsearch, tire

I'm trying to get STI working with tire/mongoid since hours. I hope someone can help me.

I've two models with different indexes. It should be possible to search both indexes over Event.search but also to search only the appropiate index with CoursePlan.search.

First Model: Event

```
# encoding: utf-8
class Event
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  # rest of class omitted...

  # Elasticsearch
  index_name  "events" # Indexname /initializers/tire.rb
  mapping do
    indexes :_id, :index => :not_analyzed
    indexes :title
    indexes :place
    indexes :description
    indexes :fill_out
    indexes :current_user_keyword, analyzer: "keyword"
  end
```

Second Model: CoursePlan

```
# encoding: utf-8
class CoursePlan < Event
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks
  include TimeHelper

  # rest of class omitted...

  # Elasticsearch
  index_name  "course_plans"
  tire.index.add_alias "events"
  mapping do
    indexes :_id, :index => :not_analyzed
    indexes :title
    indexes :place
    indexes :description
    indexes :fill_out
    indexes :user_email
    indexes :course_title
    indexes :course_area
    indexes :course_user_email
    indexes :date
  end
```

I've tried already the solution from richarddong, see [tire issue #178](https://github.com/karmi/retire/issues/178). But this only seems to work under some circumstances.

Is there a working solution for this problem? Maybe i just got something wrong.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this answer,

[Search multiple models with Tire and ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950470/search-multiple-models-with-tire-and-)

```
     def browse
        @search_items = Tire.search(['posts_index', 'channels_index'],{load: true}) do |search|
          search.query do |q|
            q.string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" if params[:query].present? 
          end
          search.sort { by :created_at, "desc" } if params[:query].blank?
        end
        @results = @search_items.results
      end
```

Comment: This works, thank you. But now i've another problem. After "rake tire:import CLASS=Event FORCE=true" there are double entries in the Event-Table for every course_plan. Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't get you. Double entries in the table? Did you mean database table? The tire import doesn't modify anything in the database. All it uses is the select query.

Comment: No, i mean the elasticsearch "table". After the import rake task there are double entries for each course plan in elasticsearch. It seems that the import task for Events imports CoursePlans too. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: `tire.index.add_alias "events"` Why is this line added in the course plan model?

Comment: This line was added for testing. I have removed the line, still same effect.

Comment: How did you confirm there were double entries?

Comment: I found the issue in the meanwhile. Rails saved the entries doubled in the database. So this was not related to Elasticsearch. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad that you found the issue. Happy to help... :)